# onChange fileField play uploaded audio file in yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to play the uploaded audio(.wav) file onChange fileField

the following code is not posting values

```
<?php echo $form->fileField($model,'file_loc',
    array('onChange'=>CHtml::ajax(array('type'=>'POST',
     'url'=>array("playaudio"),'update'=>'#audio')))); ?>
```

onChange it is calling action(playaudio) in controller but not posting anything

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to upload some file using ajax called by this onChange function?

Comment: @MazIqbal thanks for the comment.. i'm uploading the file using cactiveform's filefield and accessing using ajax on change

Comment: Where are you posting to? A controller? Also what data are you passing across? Or is supposed to be being passed across

Comment: @TheHumbleRat the above form field belong to model $a and posting it to model $a's controller.'playaudio' is method in the same controller. At the end i'm updating the div with id=audio.. but i'm not getting the uploaded file name....